# Functions change outputs depending on whether I call both or just one

Tags: c

I am learning C for the first time after being way more familiar with java and for this program it needs two lines of input for a deck of cards and it will say how many of the cards in a row are of the same suit and how many are in ascending order.

My problem is I think I have both of my functions working and they seem to work independently but when I try to run both of them and then output both answers it either displays nothing or instead of 5 will say 1118234.

I'm also not sure why I get a segmentation fault when I comment out the for loop in main, but with the for loop it works... except that it doesn't use the counter correctly? I am not sure where to start and would appreciate any help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

const int DECKSIZE = 52;

int sameSuitCount(char firstHalf[DECKSIZE], char secondHalf[DECKSIZE]);
int ascendingCount(char firstHalf[DECKSIZE], char secondHalf[DECKSIZE]);

int main() {
    int numTests = 0, sameSuit = 0, ascending = 0;
    scanf("%d", &numTests);

    for (int i = 0; i < numTests; i++) {
        char first[DECKSIZE+1];
        scanf("%s", first);

        char second[DECKSIZE+1];
        scanf("%s", second);

        sameSuit = sameSuitCount(first, second);
        ascending = ascendingCount(first, second);
        printf("\n%d\n", sameSuit);
        printf("\n%d", ascending);
        
    }

    return 0;
}

int sameSuitCount(char firstHalf[DECKSIZE], char secondHalf[DECKSIZE]) {
    int count = 1, max = 0;
    strcat(firstHalf, secondHalf);
    for (int i = 3; i < (DECKSIZE*2); i += 2){
        //printf("\n%c", firstHalf[i]);
        if(firstHalf[i] == firstHalf[i-2]) {
            //printf(" is the same as %c", firstHalf[i-2]);
            count++;
            //printf(". Count = %d", count);
        }
        else {
            if (count > max){
            //printf("\nSetting max to %d", count);
            max = count;
            //printf(". Max = %d", max);
            }
            count = 1;
            //printf("Count reset to %d", count);
        }
    }
    return max;
}

int ascendingCount(char firstHalf[DECKSIZE], char secondHalf[DECKSIZE]){
    int count = 1, max = 0;
    strcat(firstHalf, secondHalf);
    for (int i = 0; i < (DECKSIZE*2); i += 2){
        //printf("\n%c", firstHalf[i]);
        if( !isdigit(firstHalf[i])) {
            //printf(" is not a digit");
            switch(firstHalf[i]) {
                case 'T':
                    firstHalf[i] = 58;
                    break;
                case 'J':
                    firstHalf[i] = 59;
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                    firstHalf[i] = 60;
                    break;
                case 'K':
                    firstHalf[i] = 61;
                    break;
                case 'A':
                    firstHalf[i] = 62;
                    break;
            }
        }
        if( firstHalf[i] == (firstHalf[i-2] + 1)   ) {
            //printf(". Is ascending %c", firstHalf[i-2]);
            count++;
        }
        else if (firstHalf[i] == 50 && firstHalf[i-2] == 62) {
            //printf(". Is ascending %c", firstHalf[i-2]);
            count++;
        }
        else {
            if (count > max){
            max = count;
            }
            count = 1;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Sorry for all the printf's littered around trying to debug also.

Comment: Both of your functions contain loops that access the passed in arrays out of bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand how `strcat` works.

It does not allocate any memory, it only copies from one array to another.
It is also a dangerous function, because in C, strings are just arrays of characters, and they are passed to `strcat` as pointers, so it can not know how big the arrays are.

C arrays are not objects like Java arrays and don't contain information about their size at runtime.

So, when you do this:

```
strcat(firstHalf, secondHalf);
```

What happens is the function searches for the fist null character (`\0`) in `firstHalf`, then starts copying contents of `secondHalf` starting with that memory position.

It will continue copying until it finds a null character in `secondHalf`, even if it runs out of memory in `firstHalf`.

It will just keep clobbering whatever memory is next, with unpredictable results.

That is why sometimes you get segfault and sometimes random data.

You need to do something like this:

```
char temp[(DECKSIZE*2) + 1];
strncpy(temp, fistHalf, sizeof(temp));
strncat(temp, secondHalf, sizeof(temp));
```

This way you are guaranteed to have enough memory, and using `strncat` makes sure no matter what this memory will not be exceeded.

That is what the third parameter is for - it tells the function the maximum number of bytes that can be copied in case null character is not found.

Also, since you pass these arrays by pointer, `ascendingCount` will modify the original array!

That is why you have different behavior when calling both functions in a row.
There is no way in C to pass strings by value, so if you will probably want to use a temporary array for the modifications if you do not want to loose the original input between function calls.

Comment: `strncat()` is rarely correct. The resulting string will not be null-terminated if there isn't room. If there's any possibilility that `DECKSIZE*2+1` isn't enough, use `strlen(firstHalf)+strlen(secondHalf)+1`

Comment: In particular, if `strncpy()` doesn't add a null terminator, the `strncat()` after it will have undefined behavior.

Comment: @Barmar true, but nothing in the code relies on the result of `strncat` being null terminated. In fact, both functions assume all members of the array have been initialized with valid values. For the `strncpy` to fail to add null terminator the `scanf` in main needs to exceed expected input size and that means memory is probably corrupted before the function is ever called. But this is a beginner program, and getting around `scanf` if more for production code.

Comment: That's all true. But I don't like the idea of teaching beginners about `strncat()`, they're more likely to use it inappropriately.